# LoginStatus control not working logging with basic validation using database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a login control in login.aspx page that validates user by checking in database for username password using a stored procedure(Validation() method given below).I have used the following code

```
  protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (Validation(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
    {

        Session["Logged"] = "Yes";
        Session["User"] = "Admin";
        Session["msg"] = "";
        e.Authenticated = true;
        Response.Redirect("/umkgp/admin/gallerymanager.aspx");
      //  "Successfully Logged In";

    }
     else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }

  }
```

Now when I am using LoginStatus control it is not changing display text from login to logout.I know that LoginStatus control based on IsAuthenticated property.In my case i guess IsAuthenticated is not set to true.How to make it work.Here is the code for LoginStatus control

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="/umkgp/admin/admin.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="/umkgp/home.aspx" OnLoggingOut="Logout_Click"/> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

(n.b.I have not used membership or roles).Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line

```
 Response.Redirect("/umkgp/admin/gallerymanager.aspx");
```

with this one

```
     FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName,false);
   //this will tell the asp.net who logged in and it will redirect to the requested page or the default page
```

**Update:** If you want to set a default location go open your web.cofig file and find the authentication tag

and modify it this way

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/mydefaultpage.aspx"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: It works fine but redirect to default.aspx.I need it redirect to admin/default.aspx .please help

Answer (score 1):

from MSDN

> By default, login controls integrate with ASP.NET membership and
>   ASP.NET forms authentication to help automate user authentication for
>   a Web site.

you can get an overview how to implemet the login control in msdn [Login Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As you say your are not using asp.net membership so you the system doesn't know you are logged in and have an internal record of this.

To work around this issue you should create a custom membership provider which wraps your validation code and then all of the other asp.net membership integrated controls will automatically work with your membershipprovider:

- http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+custom+membershipprovider